# Can one still use react-navigation 2.x after upgrading to react-native 0.59.x?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

We spent a lot of time upgrading from react-native 0.57 to 0.59. Now we are down to errors which, after research, seem to be related to react-navigation (for example: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3326). 
The project is still using react-navigation 2.16, and we would like to do the upgrade to 3.x separately. 
So my question is: is anyone using 2.x version in a project migrated to 0.59? Is that an option?

Comment: 'react-native' and 'react-navigation' are separate modules It is not dependent on each other, so it does not matter to the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone else facing this issue:
I fixed this by downgrading `react-redux` from `7.1.0` to `5.1.1`